# Logical Operator Not Working Properly In Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, logical-operators

Finally after struggling a lot I came here for help..

I have a data frame which is result of groupby function and looks like this

```
 >>temp.head()

     PO_Amount  PO_Amount_Mean  id     
0     3756.6          3756.6     0
1     3756.6          3756.6     1
2    11269.8         11269.8     2
3    11269.8         11269.8     3
4     3756.6          3756.6     4


temp.dtypes
Out[141]: 
PO_Amount         float64
PO_Amount_Mean    float64
id                  int32
dtype: object
```

I am trying to fetch the data if PO_Amount equals PO_Amount_Mean

```
temp[temp['PO_Amount']==temp['PO_Amount_Mean']]
Out[142]: 
   PO_Amount  PO_Amount_Mean  id
0     3756.6          3756.6   0
1     3756.6          3756.6   1
4     3756.6          3756.6   4
6     3756.6          3756.6   6
```

Don't know why index 2 and 3 are coming in output. Please help.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "are coming in output" you actually mean the opposite.  If pandas thinks they're not equal, you should look at the difference: what does `temp['PO_Amount'] - temp['PO_Amount_Mean']` show?

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem, the whole dataframe shows up when I try

Comment: This is probably a floating point precision issue.  Pandas is working exactly as expected, but you'll need to either cast amount and mean to decimals first or use something like `np.close` to compare the floating point columns.

Comment: Try looking at `print(temp.PO_Amount[2])` and `print(temp.PO_Amount_Mean[2])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All for your replies. It's the floating point precision issue.

```
temp.PO_Amount_Mean[2]
Out[10]: 11269.800000000001

temp.PO_Amount[2]
Out[11]: 11269.8
```

Comment: but is there any way to compare such floating point, except rounding off them?

Comment: You could use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html).  I believe this case lies within the default tolerance